# How to remove automatically applied background color to the body?

Tags: javascript, css, chart.js

I'm working on a Covid-19 tracking web app and utilizing chartJS to display data from an API.
Applied background color to * in CSS but somehow there are empty spaces around the Canvas.
I inspected it on Chrome, and somehow background color of white is applied to the body, which I never wrote. How to remove this automatically applied background color?
Thank you in advance. :)

[image: Inspection on Google Chrome]

JS CODE

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
    let myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'line',
      data: {
        labels: date,
        datasets: [
          {
            label: 'Total',
            data: total,
            borderColor: '#cf0000',
            fill: false,
          },
          {
            label: 'Recovered',
            data: recovered,
            borderColor: '#4ca1a3',
            fill: false,
          },
          {
            label: 'Deaths',
            data: deaths,
            borderColor: '#907fa4',
            fill: false,
          },
```

HTML CODE

```
 <div class="container">
        <h1 class="text-center mt-3 heading">COVID-19 Tracker</h1>
        <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
    * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #e7d4b5;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed

```
<div class="container"> -> <div class="container-fluid">
```

and the side spaces with white background are filled with the background color that I wrote.

I guess it was more on the Bootstrap side of the problem.
After changing the class to container-fluid, the chart stretched to fill the screen, so I added padding to the chart to have some spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Add some CSS to your code and set the background color to transparent.

```
body{
   background-color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: Your screen has to be some color no matter what. If your body is the only thing showing on that part of the screen, the color will default to white.

Comment: I already added 'background-color: #e7d4b5;' and still, those two parts are white... any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Can you please attach full code using codepen, jsfiddle, htmlfile ect...